# Converting a string to date in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, data-cleaning

I am working on a table where I have two cols named **birth** and **death** with dates as strings(to be specific character varying).

I want to calculate the age by using those two columns. If any one of the values is missing, i.e. if either birth is missing or death is missing then it should return 'unknown' (By the way in the table that I am working with the missing values are given as **None**)

When I try to convert them into date either they are giving me an error or they are giving a wrong age.

For Example, let's say these are the birth and death dates respectively:
birth: 0133-01-30T00:53:28+00:53
death: 0193-07-01T00:53:28+00:53

I used the the following command:
`CAST(death as date) - CAST(birth as date)`
But this is returning ages such as *2210* or just some absurd age
**BY THE WAY I AM DOING THIS IN THE JUPYTER NOTEBOOK USING POSTGRESQL**

Comment: and how does the string in your table look like, which is resulting in this wrong date? And also how are your trying to convert them ?

Comment: I've mentioned how the date string looks in the question.

Comment: ok, but the year `0133` ? What calendar are you using ?

Comment: The dataset is about emperors so that is why it is like that

Comment: ah, you are taling about [Marcus Severus Didius Julianus, Roman Emperor, born in Milan, Italy (d. 193)](https://www.onthisday.com/date/133/january/30)  

Comment: yeah, Something similar I am just trying to clean the data given to me, and I am to calculate the age with the given birth and death columns along with other tasks. This is just one of the tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239182/discussion-between-karthik-bhandary-and-luuk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use postgresql `age` function to calculate the age.

Example:

```
SELECT coalesce(age('0193-07-01T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp, '0133-01-30T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp)::text, 'Unknown');
          age
------------------------
 60 years 5 mons 2 days
(1 row)
```

To get years:

```
SELECT coalesce(EXTRACT(years FROM age('0193-07-01T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp, '0133-01-30T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp))::text, 'Unknown');

 extract
---------
      60
(1 row)

SELECT coalesce(EXTRACT(years FROM age('0193-07-01T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp, null))::text, 'Unknown');
 coalesce
----------
 Unknown
(1 row)
```

Comment: can you show that with an example. It would be really helpful

Comment: How can I only get the year as the result?

Comment: I tried as you shown but instead of years, I am only getting days in the result.

Comment: @KarthikBhandary  `select EXTRACT(years FROM age('0193-07-01T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp, '0133-01-30T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp));`

Comment: How to get it as an int like I don't want any decimals in the age

Comment: If possible instead of putting none in the row I would like to put 'Unkown'

Comment: Try to read about the [CASE WHEN](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-case-statement/) statement.

Comment: @KarthikBhandary you can use `coalesce` function: `select coalesce(EXTRACT(years FROM age('0193-07-01T00:53:28+00:53'::timestamp, null))::text, 'Unknown');`

Comment: @valeryViktorovsky Should I be using that function just like that or in the case ?

Comment: @KarthikBhandary sure, just replace test values with your column names, something like `SELECT coalesce(EXTRACT(years FROM age(death, birth))::text, 'Unknown');`

Comment: @ValeryViktorovsky ok I got it. Also add the coalesce in you answer above.